# Appium desktop keep on asking for “platformName” capability even if it is added

Tags: appium-desktop

I am using Appium Desktop app. After adding all the capabilities. When I Start session, I got an error "An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: You must include a platformName capability" 
Screenshot

Answer (score 3):

Like Pankaj Mishra say,  it is really.
The APPIUM Desktop UI have some bugs and the only way to solve this problem it's typing the capibilities directly in the fields and never copy paste or edit like a JSON format.

Screenshot of the correct way to do the configuration

[image: Screenshot of the correct way to do the configuration]

Comment: Copy & Pasted my json into the Desired Capabilities fields to get this to work. Looks exactly like my json, but it finally worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

APPIUM Desktop UI have some bugs as a result you get this error even if the capabilties are present.
You can refer [Here](https://automationlab0000.wordpress.com/2018/12/31/appium-desktop-for-locating-elements/) to avoid above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, you made a **spelling** mistake:

**f**latformName: android

**f**latformVersion: 8.1

You need to fix `f` to `p` and it will work perfectly for you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enter "platformName". Not "platformName ". Can you see the difference? Second one has a hidden space which could often happen when you copy-past the capability name.

Comment: What is the difference between "platformName" and "platformName "? The blank? And more important, what is the new insight your answer contributes, in comparison to existing answers who also point out spelling mistakes (just much more convincingly), like https://stackoverflow.com/a/55399941/7733418

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

make you've write correct words "platformName:" and check your json representation.

Comment: This is a duplicate of an of existing answer, by @kivindra de silva. When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers. Remember to review all existing answers first.